# Media Element show video icons for few seconds while it is audio

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm  working on some media related thing in Windows 8.1 and i came across one behavior that when I'm trying to play audio files from network media element shows video icons toolbar for few seconds  however once the loading gets completed audio toolbar appears.
Please help.

Comment: We can only help *if* you post the relevant code. Without it, there's no way to know what may be the problem.

Comment: Following is the line of code :<MediaElement x:Name="EtextAudio" Visibility="Visible"  AutoPlay="True" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" Height="100" Width="400"
        Source="{Binding LinkObjectModel.LinkValue}"  />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What transport controls are displayed is determined once the file’s header has been parsed. This is due to the fact that modern file containers can contain audio video or both. I think your best bet is to hide the transport controls (AreTransportControlsEnabled = false) until the file header has been loaded. Handle the MediaElement.MediaOpened event and set AreTransportControlsEnabled = true. This should solve your problem.

[MediaElement.MediaOpened](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.mediaopened.aspx)

[MediaElement.AreTransportControlsEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.aretransportcontrolsenabled.aspx)

I hope this helps,

James